# How can an extended class add buttons to the super class' frame?

Tags: java, swing

I am new to Java GUI so I'm sorry if the question seems 'stupid'.

I have a class named MainFrame that is extended by a class Color(that i want to add buttons in order to control the colour of the word in the main frame.)

How can i add the buttons from Color class to the MainFrame class?

I have tried to access the panel from the superclass but for some reason the textarea does not appear.

Also i have an inner class that implements action listener and gets passed an instance of the class MainFrame(the class contains all the actions ..)

```
class main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        MainFrame = new MainFrame();
        ex.setVisible(true);
        ex.setDefaultCloseOperation(WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    }
}

public class MainFrame extends JFrame {


    int size = 400;
    ArrayList<String> mylist = new ArrayList<>();
    JLabel label = new JLabel();
    String addedWord;
    JTextArea text = new JTextArea(10,10);
    JLabel myname= new JLabel("");
    JPanel mainp = new JPanel();



    public MainFrame() {

        super("Mainframe");
        myname.setForeground(Color.gray);
        ArrayList<String> mylist2 = new ArrayList<>();
        JButton addword = new JButton("Add ");
        JButton displayword = new JButton("Display ");
        // OTHER CODE IS ADDED TO CONTROL EACH BUTTON'S ACTIONS ETC..


      class Buttons implements ActionListener {

        MainFrame theApp;
        int actionMade;


        public Buttons(MainFrame app, int action) {

            theApp = app;
            actionMade = action;

        }
```

THE CLASS THAT EXTENDS MainFrame .

```
public class Color extends MainFrame {

    MainFrame app;
    int checkr;
    int checkb;
    int chekg;



    public Color(MainFrame app) {
        this.app = app;
        JTextArea red = new JTextArea("Red");
HERE I TRY TO ACCESS THE 'mainp' panel from the superclass but it wont be added. 
        --> mainp.add(red);
```

Comment: can you show us a Exercise1  class?

Comment: Exercise1 class was the MainFrame that was changed , sorry about that . I edited the code just now

Answer (score 0):

The Color class should NOT extend MainFrame. The class is NOT a JFrame.

It is simply a helper class you created. It does not need to extend anything. By default it will extend Object.

```
this.app = app;
JTextArea red = new JTextArea("Red");
// HERE I TRY TO ACCESS THE 'mainp' panel from the superclass but it wont be added. 
--> mainp.add(red);
```

You can't access a variable directly in another class. You need a reference to the class to access the variable. So the code should be:

```
app.mainp.add(red);
```

Now in your MainFrame class you need to use:

```
public JPanel mainp = new JPanel();
```

to give other classes permission to access the variable directly.

Note, this is NOT a good design. You should generally NOT make "public" variables.

Instead you should create a method in the `MainFrame` class:

```
public JPanel getMainPanel()
{
    return mainp;
};
```

Then the code in the Color class would be:

```
app.getMainPanel().add(red);
```

Comment: ok thanks. where should i include the ' Color c = new Color(); ?, should i put it in the MainFrame class?

Comment: You still need to pass the reference to the MainFrame class when you create the Color object, so yes.

Comment: @JohnMichael, glad it helped. Don't forget to "accept" the answer by clicking on the checkmark so people know the problem has been solved.